# Gradle Installation

Tags: gradle

I am following the below link to install/configure Gradle. 
http://www.360logica.com/blog/2015/11/how-to-configure-gradle-on-windows-machine.html
I ended up downloading gradle in my V:\ drive instead of C:. As a result, in step 7, I put V:\gradle-2.8 as the variable path name. I am not sure what to do for steps 8 onwards (I don't see a PATH that starts with V:\ in the System Variables) because I didn't put this in my C drive. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GRADLE_HOME` is `V:\gradle-2.8` , as opposed to `C:\Program Files\gradle-2.8` in the tutorial. Thats perfectly alright.

In Step 8: do this

```
Variable name: GRADLE_HOME
Variable value: V:\gradle-2.8
```

In Step 9: No change.

```
Select “path” variable under the “System Variables” section and click on “Edit” button.
```

Step 10: No change.

```
Go to the end of variable value and add “;%GRADLE_HOME%\bin” and click on “OK” button.
```

**Why it works ?**

When you give path variable as `;%GRADLE_HOME%\bin;` Since you have already defined a variable called `GRADLE_HOME =  V:\gradle-2.8` , the path variable will get substituted and resolved to `V:\gradle-2.8\bin`.

This can be verified by issuing `echo %PATH%` in cmd. You wont see `GRADLE_HOME` in the output because it was replaced with `V:\gradle-2.8`

**What happens when your issue gradle in cmd ?**

When you issue 'gradle' command in your windows commandline, it will look for a binary name 'gradle' in the paths defined by `PATH` , since there will be a binary named gradle.exe inside the `V:\gradle-2.8\bin` , it will be executed. In Linux the steps are similar conceptually.